# Unfair coins connected in a game

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I would like to ask the following question.

> There are 3 coins ($A,B$ and $C$) that are biased with probability of tails equal to $t_a, t_b$ and $t_c$ respectively.   The coins are tossed: $m_a$ times for coin-$A$, $m_b$ times for coin-$B$, and $m_c$ times for coin-$C$, though with no specific order (the order is uniformly random).   There are $k$ slots that are filled with the coins when tails is a result.   When all $k$ slots are filled the game stops.
>
> What is the function / expression that I should use to find the probability that $s_a$ slots from coin A, $s_b$ slots from coin B and $s_c$ slots from coin C are filled with $s_a + s_b + s_c \leqslant k$?

Comment: I would strongly consider learning to type up my posts here. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: There's not enough information to answer the question. You need to specify either an order or a distribution for the orders. As the question is currently phrased, we can only guess that the order might be uniformly randomly drawn from all possible orders.

Comment: Yes the order is uniform and random

Comment: Please add that information to the question; people shouldn't have to read through the comment thread to understand the question.

Comment: So are the $m_a$,  $m_b$,  $m_c$ determined prior to the game, or after its completion?  In other words, is it possible for the game to terminate with fewer than $k$ slots filled once the prescribed number of tosses $(m_a+m_b+m_c)$ have taken place, or are the $m$'s just a suggested notation for the number of times each coin ends up being tossed in the course of tossing coins uniformly at randum until $k$ tails occur?

Comment: Or equivalently, could the number of times coin $C$ (for instance) is tossed be less than $m_c$ if the $k$-th  tail comes prior to the $m_c$-th toss?

Comment: Yes. There are two different options. 1. The times the coins are tossed results in fewer than k slots being filled. 2. The times the coins are tossed results in exactly k slots being filled and then the game stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So clearly if we removed the rule that we stop after $k$ tails, the formula would simply be $$P_m(s_a,s_b,s_c)=\prod_{i \in \{a,b,c\}}t_i^{s_i}(1-t_i)^{m_i-s_i}{m_i \choose s_i}$$
In cases where $s_a+s_b+s_c\lt k$, the rule never applies, and the above formula is correct. $$ P(s_a,s_b,s_c)= P_m(s_a,s_b,s_c); \quad s_a+s_b+s_c\lt k$$
In cases where $s_a+s_b+s_c= k$, we consider what would happen if we kept going until we had flipped each coin the prescribed number of times, possibly accumulating additional tails.

For any given $z_a,z_b,z_c$ and $s_a,s_b,s_c$ where $z_i \ge s_i$ and $\sum _{i}s_i=k$ for $i\in \{a,b,c\}$, the probability of flipping $z_i$ tails on coin $i$ with $s_i$ of those coming in the first $k$ tails is $$\Phi(z_a,z_b,z_c,s_a,s_b,s_c)=\frac{{z_a \choose s_a} {z_b \choose s_b}{z_c \choose s_c}}{z_a+z_b+z_c \choose k} P_m(z_a,z_b,z_c)$$
so the total probability for $s_a+s_b+s_c= k$ is
$$ P(s_a,s_b,s_c)=\sum_{z_a=s_a}^{m_a} \sum_{z_b=s_b}^{m_b}\sum_{z_c=s_c}^{m_c}\Phi(z_a,z_b,z_c,s_a,s_b,s_c); \quad s_a+s_b+s_c= k$$

Not the prettiest formula, nor the easiest to calculate, but it is correct.

Comment: Can we check if it is correct?

Comment: For example what is the probability that 1 slot is filled from tails of coinA when coin A is tossed 2 times, CoinB is tossed 8 times and coinC is tossed 3 times?

Comment: First of all, we need to know $k$ to make that calculation.  Secondly, since you only provided $s_a$, It would require summing over all possible values of $s_b$ and $s_c$, and then (for each case where $s_a+s_b+s_c=k$) summing over possible values of $z_i$ for $i \in \{a,b,c\}$.  This is a long, drawn out calculation which, frankly, I don't want to do, but you're welcome to, and it will produce the correct answer.  There's probably a way to simplify the formula, too, but I've forgotten a lot of the combinatoric identities that would help with that, so for now, this is what you get.

Comment: Too ease your concerns about its correctness (or at least my confidence in its correctness), I removed "I believe" from the last line.  The formula _**is**_ correct, it's just really cumbersome to use.  If you're going to try to use it as is, I suggest limiting yourself to small values of $m_i$, $s_i$, and $k$, or writing a simple program to crunch the numbers for you.

Comment: What does z represent exactly?

Comment: We imagine that we don't stop after $k$ tails, always flipping coin $i$ $m_i$  times.  $z_i$ is the number of tails we get from coin $i$ after all $m_i$ flips are complete, while $s_i$ is the number we had when our total number of tails from all coins was $k$, and we should have stopped.

Comment: So if we want to calculate the probability that 1 slot is filled by coin A in a game with 2 coin A tosses, 8 tosses of Coin B and 3 coin tosses from coin C what is the exact expression that I will have to use?

Comment: Again, you need to know $k$ to do that.  If you did, you would use the bottom expression for each possible pair of values for $s_b$ and $s_c$, and sum the results:$$\sum_{s_b=0}^{\min \left( 8, k-1 \right)} \sum_{s_c=0}^{\min \left( 3 , k-s_b-1 \right)}P(1,s_b,s_c)$$  You would also have to use the second expression for cases where the $s_i$ don't total at least $k$